# postfix/sendmail can't read main.cf file

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I'm trying to configure a mailserver, but when i run:

```
echo "test email" | mail -s "test" myemail@gmail.com -aFrom hello@mydomain.com
```

and check `tail /var/log/mail.err` I get `Aug  8 13:36:37 localhost postfix/sendmail[7034]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: Permission denied`.

Here are `/etc/postfix` folder permissions:

```sh
root@localhost:~# ls -la /etc/postfix/
total 156
drwxr-x---   5 root vmail  4096 Aug  8 13:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 112 root root   4096 Aug  8 13:33 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root vmail   100 Aug  8 11:38 dynamicmaps.cf
drwxr-xr-x   2 root vmail  4096 Jun 19  2020 dynamicmaps.cf.d
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root vmail  3126 Aug  8 13:09 main.cf
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root vmail  1390 Aug  7 15:58 main.cf.orig
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root vmail 27120 Aug  7 15:24 main.cf.proto
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     31 Aug  7 15:25 makedefs.out -> /usr/share/postfix/makedefs.out
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root vmail  6511 Aug  8 12:27 master.cf
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root vmail  6208 Aug  7 16:17 master.cf.orig
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root vmail  6208 Aug  7 15:24 master.cf.proto
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root vmail   148 Aug  7 16:13 mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root vmail   139 Aug  7 16:12 mysql-virtual-email2email.cf
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root vmail   137 Aug  7 23:53 mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root vmail   135 Aug  7 16:13 mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root vmail 10268 Jun 19  2020 postfix-files
drwxr-xr-x   2 root vmail  4096 Aug  8 11:38 postfix-files.d
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root vmail 11532 Jun 19  2020 postfix-script
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root vmail 29872 Jun 19  2020 post-install
drwxr-xr-x   2 root vmail  4096 Jun 19  2020 sasl
```

I am sorry if my question is badly formatted but i am new here.
I will update if it helps you.

Comment: What user is postfix using? Is it a member of the vmail group?

Comment: Directories and files in `/etc/postfix/` are usually user and group `root`, with specific exceptions such as DKIM keys, with configuration files having `0644` permissions (and private keys `0640`). I'm not an expert at all configurations, I'm just not clear why `vmail` group would need to be assigned to those files.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider In Ubuntu `postfix` installed from repos runs `chroot` in `/var/spool/postfix/`, if I understand those configurations correctly.

Comment: Do you have SELinux activated?

Comment: @RomeoNinov The post already shows SELinux is disabled.

Comment: I'd try chmod 755 /etc/postfix, for a start.

Comment: I think this user has left us, and I just noticed that SE no longer publishes the user last visit, so who knows if this user will ever return. I'm wondering if these permissions are the result of one of those pesky admin panel things?